# Laravel - How to Add Custom field in FORGOT PASSWORD

Tags: laravel, authentication, forgot-password

I am trying to add one more field to forgot password which is **STAFF ID & EMAIL**. If **STAFF ID and EMAIL** is correct then the system should send reset password link.

It seems laravel default only allow **email** for forgot password. Is there anyways to add **STAFF ID** and **verify** both field before send email?

> **vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/SendsPasswordResetEmails.php**

```
    <?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

trait SendsPasswordResetEmails
{
    /**
     * Display the form to request a password reset link.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLinkRequestForm()
    {
        return view('auth.passwords.email');
    }

    /**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateEmail($request);

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $this->credentials($request)
        );

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                    ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($request, $response)
                    : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }

    /**
     * Validate the email for the given request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate(['email' => 'required|email']);
    
    }

    /**
     * Get the needed authentication credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only('email');
        
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a successful password reset link.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetLinkResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return back()->with('status', trans($response));
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a failed password reset link.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetLinkFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return back()
                ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to override the `PasswordBroker` and `DatabaseTokenRepository` which is actually a lot of work for something that could have been achieved with a little modification to the `canResetPasswordContract`. The current implementation assumes resetting a password is all about the user and undermines the importance of getting the request information such as the ip address; and there's also the issue of efficient table indexing.

Nevertheless, I came up with a possible replacement of the shipped `ForgotPasswordController` that should be sufficient for most use cases to change the payload associated with reset password if you would like to use a different table structure without overriding everything.

Keep in mind that

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\PasswordReset;
use App\Models\User;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset emails and
    | includes a trait which assists in sending these notifications from
    | your application to your users. Feel free to explore this trait.
    |
    */    
    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;
    
    //in minutes
    protected $throttle = 60;

    /**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateEmail($request);

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $user = User::where($this->credentials($request))->first();

        if (is_null($user)) {
            return $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, PasswordBroker::INVALID_USER);
        }

        $reset = PasswordReset::where(
            'email', $user->getEmailForPasswordReset()
        )->first();

        if ($reset && $this->tokenRecentlyCreated($reset)) {
            return $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, PasswordBroker::RESET_THROTTLED);
        }

        $token = $this->createToken($request, $user, $reset);
        //keep in mind that saved token is hashed version of this
        $user->sendPasswordResetNotification($token);

        return $this->sendResetLinkResponse($request, Password::RESET_LINK_SENT);
    }

    /**
     * Create a ne password reset token
     * 
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param Model $user 
     * @param Model $reset
     */
    public function createToken($request, $user, $reset)
    {
        $email = $user->getEmailForPasswordReset();

        if ($reset) {
            $reset->delete();
        }

        // We will create a new, random token for the user so that we can e-mail them
        // a safe link to the password reset form. Then we will insert a record in
        // the database so that we can verify the token within the actual reset.
        $token = $this->createNewToken();

        PasswordReset::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'email' => $email,
            'token' => bcrypt($token),
            'created_at' => now(),
            'ip_address' => $request->ip()
        ]);

        return $token;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new token for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function createNewToken()
    {
        return hash_hmac('sha256', Str::random(40), $this->getHashKey());
    }

    /**
     * Replicate hash key used by DatabaseTokenRepository
     */
    public function getHashKey()
    {
        $key = config('app.key');
        if (Str::startsWith($key, 'base64:')) {
            $key = base64_decode(substr($key, 7));
        }
        return $key;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the token was recently created.
     *
     * @param  Model  $token
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function tokenRecentlyCreated($token)
    {
        if ($this->throttle <= 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return Carbon::parse($token->created_at)->addSeconds(
            $this->throttle
        )->isFuture();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My current method works as expected and i have been using it for about 1 year. Btw your method looks clean and practical. Definitely will try to enhance it. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Finally manage to add **staff ID** in credentials :)

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

trait SendsPasswordResetEmails
{
    /**
     * Display the form to request a password reset link.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLinkRequestForm()
    {
        return view('auth.passwords.email');
    }

    /**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateEmail($request);

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $this->credentials($request)
        );

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                    ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($request, $response)
                    : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }

    /**
     * Validate the email for the given request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate(['email' => 'required|email'],['StaffID' => 'required']);
    
    }

    /**
     * Get the needed authentication credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only('email', 'StaffID');
        
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a successful password reset link.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetLinkResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return back()->with('status', trans($response));
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a failed password reset link.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetLinkFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return back()
                ->withInput($request->only('email','StaffID'))
                ->withErrors(['email' => 'We cant find a user with that Staff ID and Email']);
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker();
    }
}
```

Thanks :)